# any coding to make the background filled out 100% of the browser when reduce the size of the browser

Tags: html, css, background, height, width

I was trying to make my background to become fixed even when the browser getting small and the content run to the bottom.

The problem I am facing now is, the size of my background is not standard size 1366*768, my size now is 1366*1000, therefore my website will be able to scroll.

When the browser getting small and the content narrow down, my background cannot fixed the lower part of the content, there will be white area at the bottom, is there any method to solve it?

thanks

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-image: url(img/homebg.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
    -o-background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
    background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000;
    font-family: KaiTi, "Century Gothic";
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

updated (am i correct?)

```
body {
    background: url(img/homebg.png) no-repeat top left scroll;
    background-size: auto auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000;
    font-family: KaiTi, "Century Gothic";
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

html {
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<script>
function resizeIt() {
    $("body").css("background-size", $(document).width() + "px " + $(document).height() +"px");
}
$(window).resize(function () {
    resizeIt();
});
resizeIt();
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you want to have your image stretched to the very bottom? Or...?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're looking to have the background image to cover the entire page regardless of its size. If that's the case then you might want to check: http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

Comment: @shodaburp ya, that is what I want. but the size of my background image is 1366*1000, the size of my webpage should be 1366*1000, which will be able to scroll. however when I reduce the size of the browser, my content will be longer, but my background image cant fixed that, therefore there will be white space at the bottom, is there any method to solve?

Comment: @Thauwa not stretched to the very bottom, I just want my image to cover the entire page regardless of the browser size, i want my bg image to remain static , even when the content is narrow down. I want my bg image is to become static as 1366*1100, just my content will be able to scroll. Because my bg image is not the standard size, so is there any method to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

**CSS**

```
body {
    background: url(yourImage.jpg) no-repeat top left scroll;
    background-size: auto auto;
    color: #000;
    font-family: KaiTi, "Century Gothic";
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.4;
}
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
function resizeIt() {
    $("body").css("background-size", $(document).width() + "px " + $(document).height() + "px");
}
$(window).resize(function () {
    resizeIt();
});
resizeIt();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/thauwa/P7GM4/

Comment: not working... when resize the browser, the bg image still unable to cover the entire page.

Comment: Did you check the demo? Is that what you want?

Comment: ya, this is what I want, but why cannot success?

Comment: Did you include jQuery in your test page? Did you check your web browser's console log for errors? Did you remove the `cover` properties from your CSS?

Comment: I not sure what is the "console log for errors", i have update my new coding, please do help me to check it, thanks.